# FileTreeModel Multiple Roots

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I use this code [here](http://www.chka.de/swing/tree/FileTreeModel.html) to create a file tree model. I want it to browse files. How can I add multiple roots? E.g. list C:/, D:/, E:/.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `TreeModel` can only have one root node, but you can use [`JTree.setRootVisible()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#setRootVisible%28boolean%29) to hide the root node when displaying the tree.  Modify your model to have a virtual root node that contains each filesystem root (C:\, D:\, E:\, etc.), and call `JTree.setRootVisible(false)` on your JTree.